# Convex hull aborts kernels (reproducible)

Tags: mesh, combinatorics, abort, delaunaymesh

11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)
ReleaseID -> "11.0.0.0 (5570737, 2016072801)

a set of 32 points :

```
pts={{0,1,1},{1,1,2},{1,0,3},{2,0,4},{2,-1,5},{3,-1,6},{3,0,7},{2,0,8},{1,0,7},{1,-1,6},{3,0,3},{3,1,2},{3,2,3},{3,3,2},{4,3,1},{4,4,0},{3,4,-1},{3,3,-2},{3,2,-1},{4,2,0},{5,2,-1},{6,2,0},{6,1,1},{7,1,2},{7,0,3},{6,0,4},{6,-1,5},{6,-2,4},{7,-2,3},{8,-2,4}};
```

and the instruction

```
hull = ConvexHullMesh[Drop[pts, -1]];
```

behaves normally, we can plot it like :

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Blue, Thick, Line[pts], Thin, Opacity[.1] }],  HighlightMesh[hull, {Style[1, {Gray}], Style[2, Opacity[0.1, Brown]]}] ]
```

but on my system, including the last point {8,-2,4} in the argument of ConvexHullMesh gives an immediate abort without error message.

Q1 : Does this also happen in more recent versions?
Q2 : Can this Abort be 'caught', neutralised or circumvented somehow?
It is not clear to me how AbortProtect and CheckAbort should be used in this case.

Comment: No problem with Mathematica v12.2

Comment: I tested in Wolfram Engine (Jupyter Notebook) `13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 12, 2023)` and Wolfram Cloud `13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023) `, neither crashed, plots looks alright.

Comment: Any confirmations in version 11 ? Maybe the changes since version 11.0.0 are documented in a public place? Any pointers?

Comment: I found a work-around : DelaunayMesh and BoundaryMesh both work without a problem, and equally fast. As to Q2 : AbortProtect and CheckAbort both fail to catch it.